# HTML is not applying CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am very new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to link my CSS and JS file to my HTML file, but it is not working. I have looked at many other Stack Overflow questions & answers on this problem, and none of the solutions seemed to have worked. Is there some sort of typo/problem that I am overlooking?

```
    website
    |home
        |_static
            |_home
                |_styles.css
                |_main.js
        |_templates
            |_home
                |_base.html
```

This is the top of my `base.html` file

```html
  <head>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../home/styles.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'home/main.js' %}"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
```

Here is the relevant code from settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and later

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here are the error messages in Command Prompt:

```
[05/Jun/2019 13:58:15] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1014
Not Found: /home/styles.css
[05/Jun/2019 13:58:15] "GET /static/home/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1660
[05/Jun/2019 13:58:15] "GET /home/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2304
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant settings? static root and static url

Comment: Show your `settings` file

Comment: Is debug on or off?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan debug is on.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you put in the staticfiles_dirs field?

Comment: Mind running `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 home/styles.css` and share the output

Comment: @IşıkKaplan No matching file found for 'home/styles.css'.

Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static

Comment: @PaulaC I don't have a STATICFILES_DIRS field right now.

Comment: Okay this one is a bit unlikely but, you do have staticfiles app installed right?
`'django.contrib.staticfiles'` because by default  it should look for app directories too

Comment: @IşıkKaplan I have added my installed apps to the post. I believe it is right.

Comment: Is that the entire installed apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

If this is your entire installed apps, it looks like you haven't installed your own app, and that means staticfiles apps doesn't check that directory since it is not an installed app.Adding your app here would add it to the searched paths and django-dev-server would serve the statics.

Comment: that has seemed to solve it! such a rookie mistake! thanks so much!

Comment: Happens to best of us. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

change your `../` like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/styles.css' %}">
```

Comment: For the js file, you should keep that link at the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: @Walucas [05/Jun/2019 14:22:51] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1021
[05/Jun/2019 14:22:51] "GET /static/home/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1660
[05/Jun/2019 14:22:51] "GET /static/home/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1669